# Track number of Calls/Emails from Case

Tags: email, case, tasks, email2case, logging

I would like to track on how many Calls and Email Sent/Received on Case.We have enabled email 2 case and sending emails using Send an Email button(Emails related list) on Case and Logging calls from Log a Call button(Activity History) on Case.

Now I would like to report on Number of Calls/Emails made on each case

- Created a custom pick list field 'Activity Type' with Call and Email
  as pick list options.
- Created a workflow rule to update Activity Type with Call if
  subject of Task contains 'Call' and
- Created a workflow rule to update Activity Type with'Email' if subject of 
  Task  starts with Email

I would like to run report off of Activity Type field

But second workflow is not working as expected as it doesn't update Activity Type to email.I tried by changing the workflow rule criteria from **Starts with** to **Contains**

Is my approach correct ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: From my understanding, you have no problem on creating the reports and filtering it by Activity Type, your problem is your workflow is not working as expected as it doesn't update your activity type to email? is this correct? 

if so, can you please post a photo of how you've setup your workflow rule to update the activity type.

Comment: @SeanSoriano updated

Comment: Workflow is active and when u click on Send an Email button .. 'Email:' gets appended to the Subject we enter on Task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant fire off a workflow for the task that gets created from Email to Case, just like you can't fire a workflow for using the Send an Email button. The internal workflow that Salesforce has for those is not set to fire off your workflow rules after it creates the task. Resolution of [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kqvHAAQ) idea would allow for what you want to do here. I also know this doesn't work with Process Builder either. I believe this can be done using a trigger on the Task object, but I don't know if that's the answer/solution you are looking for here. There is a knowledge base article on this [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Workflow-on-task-not-firing-based-on-email-sent-from-an-object&language=en_US) as well

Comment: Is there any other way to track number of calls/emails on case other than doing this with creating Field on task and updating it with workflow/trigger and reporting based on that Field.

Comment: I wonder if a headless flow could see the task after its been created. I kinda wanna try it. Let me see. Could also try a future method... I usually steer clear of actual triggers whenever possible.

Comment: Na process builder doesn't see the task at all at all. lol. Bummer.